# Keypress event on dynamically added element is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that is added dynamically. The `keypress` event is not working on `tr` and `td`. The event is not fired. But it fires if I use the `table` or the class of table like `'.loaded-table'`. Here is my code.

```
$(document).on("keypress", '.loaded-table tr', function (event) {
    var key = event.which;
    if(key === 13){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert();
    }
});
```

And here is the `HTML` code of dynamically loaded table.

```
<table contenteditable="true" class="table table-bordered loaded-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>father_name</th>
            <th>dob</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Robert</td>
            <td>12-04-1992</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't think that I have a problem in selecting the element for the event. You may know better. Thanks

Comment: try $('.loaded-table').on("keypress", 'tr', ...

Comment: Nice Question. +1

Comment: every-body posted answer but no one able to answer that why `.loaded-table tr` or `loaded-table tr td` is not working when table is content-editable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove `contenteditable="true"` from table tag and add it to either `tr` or `td` in order to allow keypress event to fire. In this example I have added `contenteditable="true"` to all tds for which I want to fire the keypress event.

```js
$('body').on("keypress", '.loaded-table tr td', function(e) {
    var keyC = e.keyCode;
    if (keyC == 32) {
         alert('Enter pressed');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<table class="table table-bordered loaded-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>father_name</th>
            <th>dob</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td contenteditable="true">1</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">John</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">Robert</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">12-04-1992</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

OR simply use `<input>` element

```
<tr><td><input type="text"></td>....</tr>
```

Comment: But keyCode 32 is Space. Enter key is 13.

Answer (score 3):

This works too. Notice the `,` after `.loaded-table`.

```
$(document).on("keypress", '.loaded-table, tr', function(e) {
    var keyC = e.keyCode;
    if (keyC == 32) {
         alert('Enter pressed');
    }
});
```

Comment: try here http://jsbin.com/wojoxukiqe/edit?html,js,output Am I doing something wrong there? Btw, it was working with space.